# Using apply to get a numeric value

Tags: r, math, loops, error-handling, apply

I have two columns of data, eg:

```
col1: c(1,2,3,0,7)
col2: c(4,5,6,7,3)
```

For each column I would like to compute this ratio and place it as the last value of the column:

```
 No. of values less than 5/(No. of values greater than 5 + No. of values lesser than 5)
```

The result for the first column should thus be 4/4+1 = 0.2

I'm new to R and the only way I can think of doing the above is looping through the whole column and using if-else structures. Is there a better way?

This is what I want to NOT use because it is too clunky :

```
for (a in 1:5)
{
if(col1<5){v1++;}
if(col1>5){v2++;}
}
v3<-v1/(v1+v2);
col1[6]<-v3;
```

When I do the above I get the error:

```
Error in if (col1[a] < 5) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I have ensured that all the numbers are numeric in the column, so why this error?

Comment: what about values = 5? that is, for col2, then it's 2/(2+2) = 0.5 (not counting the 5 at all in both cases)?

Comment: Values=5 are to be neglected. Should have mentioned that, my bad.

Answer (score 3):

Your maths is off.

```
DF <- data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,0,7), col2=c(4,5,6,7,3))

result <- apply(DF,2,function(x) sum(x<5)/(sum(x!=5)))
result
#col1 col2 
# 0.8  0.5
```

Comment: Sorry about the math! I understand the apply function here, but I would like to store the answer in a data frame element or a variable. When I use the apply statement and store the result in a variable "temp", I get an error saying that "dim(X) must be of positive length"

Comment: @agstudy showed already how to add the result as a row to a data.frame, but that doesn't make much sense in my opinion. I added to my answer how to store it in a vector.

Answer (score 1):

This will compute the ratio for each column and add it to the last:

```
  rbind(dat,apply(dat,2,
         function(x) c(sum(x<5)/(sum(x<5)+sum(x>5)))))
  col1 col2
1  1.0  4.0
2  2.0  5.0
3  3.0  6.0
4  0.0  7.0
5  7.0  3.0
6  0.8  0.5
```

Answer (score 1):

A matrix approach:

```
> m <- cbind(c(1,2,3,0,7), c(4,5,6,7,3))
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    2    5
[3,]    3    6
[4,]    0    7
[5,]    7    3

> colSums(m<5)/colSums(m!=5)
[1] 0.8 0.5
```